# Change text from other class with AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I have some action script in the first layer and it imports a `CustomSocket` class from an external .as file. When I receive a command on the socket I want to edit the GUI objects. For example, when I get the command `TIME 23` from the server I want to change the dynamic text box `timerBox` to the value `23`. I have a method called `processCommand(cmd:String)` in the CustomSocket class, but I don't know how to change the text. Usually you can just do `timerBox.text = "23";` but this doesn't work in an external class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'CustomSocket' is not your document class, then you need to specify some reference for your timeline in your class.

For general example,

While importing a class,

```
import CustomSocket;

csObj:CustomSocket = new CustomSocket(this);
```

then, inside class, in constructor

```
public function LibraryS(_ref:Object):void
{
  timelineRef = _ref;
}
```

then in your class you can say,

```
timelineRef.timeBox.text = "23";
```

Comment: Ok, I have access to a timeline reference in the CustomSocket class, but when I try and set the text to "23" it just goes blank, any idea what's causing this? Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, I think it was just a stupid issue with font embedding.

Comment: good, you sorted. Hope this will help someone else stuck with such issue.